# How to implement @ManyToMany with unique constraint?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I'd like to model npm package versions and their maintainers. Have a look at the following API response.

https://registry.npmjs.org/react

The package react with version `17.0.2` has multiple maintainers.

```json
    "maintainers": [
        {
            "name": "sebmarkbage",
            "email": "sebastian@calyptus.eu"
        },
        {
            "name": "gaearon",
            "email": "dan.abramov@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "acdlite",
            "email": "npm@andrewclark.io"
        },
        {
            "name": "brianvaughn",
            "email": "briandavidvaughn@gmail.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "fb",
            "email": "opensource+npm@fb.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "trueadm",
            "email": "dg@domgan.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "sophiebits",
            "email": "npm@sophiebits.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "lunaruan",
            "email": "lunaris.ruan@gmail.com"
        }
    ],
```

A maintainer can have multiple packages, e.g. `gaearon` can also be the maintainer of another package.

Here is how I'm currently doing it. This my `NpmPackageVersion.java`.

```java
@Entity
public class NpmPackageVersion {

  public NpmPackageVersion() {}

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
  @JsonManagedReference
  private Set<Maintainer> maintainers = new HashSet<>();

  public void addMaintainer(Maintainer maintainer) {
    this.maintainers.add(maintainer);
    maintainer.getNpmPackageVersions().add(this);
  }

  public void removeMaintainer(Maintainer maintainer) {
    this.maintainers.remove(maintainer);
    maintainer.getNpmPackageVersions().remove(this);
  }
}
```

Here is my `Maintainer.java`.

```java
@Entity
public class Maintainer {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "maintainers")
  @JsonBackReference
  private Set<NpmPackageVersion> npmPackageVersions = new HashSet<>();

  private String name;

  private String email;

  private String url;
}
```

Here are my database tables.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS npm_package_version (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    version TEXT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS maintainer (
    id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT,
    email TEXT UNIQUE,
    url TEXT
)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS npm_package_version_maintainers (
    npm_package_versions_id BIGINT NOT NULL REFERENCES npm_package_version,
    maintainers_id INT NOT NULL REFERENCES maintainer
)
```

As you can see I have a unique constraint for the maintainer email.

I'm now querying the npm registry and trying to store data in my database.

```java
// do the http request and use a DTO, then create a new entity
var npmPackageVersion = new NpmPackageVersion();
npmPackageVersion.setVersion(version);
// add maintainers
if (value.maintainers() != null) {
  value
  .maintainers()
  .forEach(m -> {
    var maintainer = maintainerRepository.findByEmailIgnoreCase(m.email()).orElseGet(() -> {
      var inner = new Maintainer();
      inner.setEmail(m.email());
      inner.setName(m.name());
      inner.setUrl(m.url());
      return inner;
    });
    npmPackageVersion.addMaintainer(maintainer);
  });
}

// then save the new version
```

I'm checking if a maintainer is already in the database by using the `email` field from the API response. If the maintainer is already present I use it and if not I a create a new one. I associate every maintainer with the package.

When I'm trying to save the package I'm getting the following error

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "maintainer_email_key"

I think I know why I'm getting this error. Java saves the new npm package version and at the same times tries to save all maintainers. If an already existing maintainer is part of the `maintainers` `Set` Postgres throws the error.

So my question is:
How can I prevent this error? How can I tell hiberante to only save NEW maintainers and for EXISTING maintainers only add the association to the `npm_package_version_maintainers` table? I should not try to save an existing maintainer again to the database.

---

Edit 2021/06/14

I've created a demo repo to reproduce my problem.

https://github.com/zemirco/hibernate-issue

Although I added `hashCode` and `equals` to all my entities I'm still getting the same error. I think we're close but I'm still missing something. The relation is

Package -> Version -> Maintainer

So for every package has multiple versions. Every version has multiple maintainers. The same maintainer can be in multiple versions. So in the end when I try to save the Package Hibernate tries to save all versions and all maintainers. Then I'm getting the error that a maintainer might already exist in the database.

Comment: I was not able to reproduce your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that

```
maintainerRepository.findByEmail(dto.email())
```

will return null many times for same email because your transaction is not done yet.

After that you are adding many items

```
var inner = new Maintainer();
inner.setEmail(dto.email());
inner.setName(dto.name());
inner.setUrl(dto.url());
maintainerRepository.save(inner);
return inner;
```

with same email. But this is not called before transaction is finished. And on the end of Transaction you have many calls of `maintainerRepository.save(inner);` which throws Unique Constraint Ex.

You face the same problem in the example from Github. You are adding same Maintener many times which will cause underlaying Hibernate mechanism to call save many times.

One solution that should work is to have separate method where you will first save Maintainers filtered by email. You should annotate that method with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)`

Second method also annotated with `@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` will always call just `findByEmail` and put objects inside `npmPackageVersion` or whatever other object. Here all maintainers will already be saved in database.

`(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` have some drawbacks and possible issues but what you want here as a batch job can not be easy achieved without separate transactions. Or I can not see it right now :)

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void saveMainteners(Dto dto){
    if(maintenerRepository.findByEmail(dto.getEmail) == null){
       maintenerRepository.save(new Maintener(dto));
    }
}

@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
public void addMaintener(Dto dto){
    var npmPackageVersion = new NpmPackageVersion();
    npmPackageVersion.setVersion(version);
    npmPackageVersion.setDescription(value.description());
    npmPackageVersion.setHomepage(value.homepage());
    Maintainer maintainer = maintenerRepository.findByEmail(dto.getEmail);
    npmPackageVersion.addMaintainer(maintainer);
}
```

Comment: I hade mistake in original post. Here is edit REQUIRES -> REQUIRES_NEW

Comment: Could you provide a few more details? I'm trying to implement your idea but I'm still getting some errors. You could simply add your code to my existing demo and see if your addition works https://github.com/zemirco/hibernate-issue. Thank you, it sounds like we're on the right track.

Comment: I finally found the solutions and splitting the one big method into multiple smaller ones was actually the solution. With multiple smaller ones I have better control over the transactions. Thank you!

Comment: I am glad you succeed, I am sorry I didn't have time to add those to your code directly.

Answer (score 1):

As it is usually with jpa and hibernate, the problem is the identity here. `npmPackageVersion` already has an instance of the type `Maintainer`, but when you call `npmPackageVersion.addMaintainer(maintainer);`, you're adding yet another instance, which is structurally equal (has the same fields), but the reference is different.

So in other words the object found in this line:

```
maintainerRepository.findByEmailIgnoreCase(m.email())
```

is already a child of `npmPackageVersion`, but those are two different instances, because hibernate initializes them separately.

To solve the problem you need to define a notion of identity for `Maintainer` (and preferably for all the entities):

```
@Entity
public class Maintainer {

    // fields

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Maintainer maintainer = (Maintainer) o;
        return email.equals(maintainer.getEmail());
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(email);
    }

}
```

P.S.: For performance reasons it is advisable to define `@JoiningTable` on the entities, especially if you're managing the schema manually.

Comment: That's a good advice. Although I added `equals` and `hashCode` I'm still getting the error. I created a demo repo so that you're able to reproduce my problem. https://github.com/zemirco/hibernate-issue

Comment: @zemirco: `Found non-empty schema(s) "public" but no schema history table. Use baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the schema history table.` Please make the example reproducible

Comment: I tried on multiple different machines. `git clone ...`, `docker-compose up -d` and ran the application. Works every time until the error about duplicate emails show up. Is your database already populated via flyway from another project?

Comment: @zemirco for me it only spawns the database, I can't see your application in the docker-compose.yml

Comment: You can use your IDE or `gradle` to start the application.

Comment: All answers are great and I finally found the solution. Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I can only accept one answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may have to do with the fact that in the [`Runner` class](https://github.com/zemirco/hibernate-issue/blob/975b6887aa7859a1e0b3b4a922f16ae5d05c30cb/src/main/java/com/example/demo/Runner.java#L24-L59) you are inserting duplicates values for the maintainers when saving your `NpmPackage` information:

```java
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
  var pkg = registryService.get("json2csv");
  logger.info("pkg: {}", pkg.maintainers());


  var npmPackage = new NpmPackage();
  npmPackage.setName(pkg.name());


  var versions = pkg.versions();
  if (versions != null) {
    versions.forEach(
        (version, value) -> {
          // logger.info("value: {}", value.maintainers());


          var npmPackageVersion = new NpmPackageVersion();
          npmPackageVersion.setVersion(version);
          npmPackageVersion.setDescription(value.description());
          npmPackageVersion.setHomepage(value.homepage());
          if (value.maintainers() != null) {
            value
                .maintainers()
                .forEach(
                    dto -> {
                      // You are inserting a new maintainer for every
                      // version, an it will cause duplicates emails
                      var maintainer = new Maintainer();
                      maintainer.setEmail(dto.email());
                      maintainer.setName(dto.name());
                      maintainer.setUrl(dto.url());
                      npmPackageVersion.addMaintainer(maintainer);
                    });
          }


          npmPackage.addVersion(npmPackageVersion);
        });
  }


  npmPackageRepository.save(npmPackage);
}
```

As indicated in your question, you tried using a repository in order to verify if the maintainer already exists:

```java
@Override
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
  var pkg = registryService.get("json2csv");
  logger.info("pkg: {}", pkg.maintainers());

  var npmPackage = new NpmPackage();
  npmPackage.setName(pkg.name());

  var versions = pkg.versions();

  var maintainers = new HashMap<String, Maintainer>();

  if (versions != null) {
    versions.forEach(
        (version, value) -> {
          // logger.info("value: {}", value.maintainers());

          var npmPackageVersion = new NpmPackageVersion();
          npmPackageVersion.setVersion(version);
          npmPackageVersion.setDescription(value.description());
          npmPackageVersion.setHomepage(value.homepage());
          if (value.maintainers() != null) {
            value
                .maintainers()
                .forEach(
                    dto -> {
                      var maintainer = maintainerRepository.findByEmail(dto.email()).orElseGet(() -> {                         
                        var inner = new Maintainer();
                        inner.setEmail(dto.email());
                        inner.setName(dto.name());
                        inner.setUrl(dto.url());
                        return inner;
                      });
                      npmPackageVersion.addMaintainer(maintainer);
                    });
          }

          npmPackage.addVersion(npmPackageVersion);
        });
  }

  npmPackageRepository.save(npmPackage);
}
```

But it will not work: please, be aware that, when running the program, the maintainers are not still in the database, they will be persisted later when cascading de `NpmPackage` `save` operation.

I think you can achieve the desired result using a `Map` as a closure to see if the `Maintainer` has been already processed. Please, see the following, for example:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import com.example.demo.Maintainer.Maintainer;
import com.example.demo.Maintainer.MaintainerRepository;
import com.example.demo.NpmPackage.NpmPackage;
import com.example.demo.NpmPackage.NpmPackageRepository;
import com.example.demo.NpmPackageVersion.NpmPackageVersion;
import com.example.demo.Registry.RegistryService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import java.util.HashMap;

@Component
class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);

  @Autowired private RegistryService registryService;

  @Autowired private NpmPackageRepository npmPackageRepository;

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    var pkg = registryService.get("json2csv");
    logger.info("pkg: {}", pkg.maintainers());

    var npmPackage = new NpmPackage();
    npmPackage.setName(pkg.name());

    var versions = pkg.versions();

    var maintainers = new HashMap<String, Maintainer>();

    if (versions != null) {
      versions.forEach(
          (version, value) -> {
            // logger.info("value: {}", value.maintainers());

            var npmPackageVersion = new NpmPackageVersion();
            npmPackageVersion.setVersion(version);
            npmPackageVersion.setDescription(value.description());
            npmPackageVersion.setHomepage(value.homepage());
            if (value.maintainers() != null) {
              value
                  .maintainers()
                  .forEach(
                      dto -> {
                        var maintainer = maintainers.computeIfAbsent(dto.email(), (email) -> {                        
                          var inner = new Maintainer();
                          inner.setEmail(dto.email());
                          inner.setName(dto.name());
                          inner.setUrl(dto.url());
                          return inner;
                        });
                        npmPackageVersion.addMaintainer(maintainer);
                      });
            }

            npmPackage.addVersion(npmPackageVersion);
          });
    }

    npmPackageRepository.save(npmPackage);
  }
}
```

Or you can `save` the `Maintainer` in the database the first time he/she is processed:

```java
@Component
class Runner implements CommandLineRunner {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DemoApplication.class);

  @Autowired private RegistryService registryService;

  @Autowired private NpmPackageRepository npmPackageRepository;
  
  @Autowired private MaintainerRepository maintainerRepository;

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    var pkg = registryService.get("json2csv");
    logger.info("pkg: {}", pkg.maintainers());

    var npmPackage = new NpmPackage();
    npmPackage.setName(pkg.name());

    var versions = pkg.versions();

    if (versions != null) {
      versions.forEach(
          (version, value) -> {
            // logger.info("value: {}", value.maintainers());

            var npmPackageVersion = new NpmPackageVersion();
            npmPackageVersion.setVersion(version);
            npmPackageVersion.setDescription(value.description());
            npmPackageVersion.setHomepage(value.homepage());
            if (value.maintainers() != null) {
              value
                  .maintainers()
                  .forEach(
                      dto -> {
                        var maintainer = maintainerRepository.findByEmail(dto.email()).orElseGet(() -> {                         
                          var inner = new Maintainer();
                          inner.setEmail(dto.email());
                          inner.setName(dto.name());
                          inner.setUrl(dto.url());

                          maintainerRepository.save(inner);

                          return inner;
                        });
                        npmPackageVersion.addMaintainer(maintainer);
                      });
            }

            npmPackage.addVersion(npmPackageVersion);
          });
    }

    npmPackageRepository.save(npmPackage);
  }
}
```

---

According to your comments, saving the `Maintainer`s introduced a new problem related to lazy collection initialization: sorry, I tested your code before but I was unable to identify that error, perhaps you are inserting the information several times,... I do not know.

Any way, this new problem has to do with the fact that Hibernate is trying to load the `npmPackageVersions` collection when there is not an active transaction in place.

To solve the problem, you can define your transaction boundaries properly: with the current code, Spring Data is opening a new transaction when necessary, once per every operation performed by your repositories. As a consequence, when you fetch an existing `Maintainer`, it will load the entity from the database but, as the `npmPackageVersions` collection is lazy loaded, when you `addMaintainer` and you tried to include the new version among the ones associated with the maintainer, the exception is raised, because Hibernate tries loading the association without an active transaction.

First, enable Spring declarative transaction management including the appropriate annotation `@EnableTransactionManagement`:

```java
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DemoApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

Then, mark your `Runner` `run` method as `Transactional:

```java
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

//...

@Override
@Transactional
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
  var pkg = registryService.get("json2csv");
  logger.info("pkg: {}", pkg.maintainers());

  var npmPackage = new NpmPackage();
  npmPackage.setName(pkg.name());

  var versions = pkg.versions();

  if (versions != null) {
    versions.forEach(
        (version, value) -> {
          // logger.info("value: {}", value.maintainers());

          var npmPackageVersion = new NpmPackageVersion();
          npmPackageVersion.setVersion(version);
          npmPackageVersion.setDescription(value.description());
          npmPackageVersion.setHomepage(value.homepage());
          if (value.maintainers() != null) {
            value
                .maintainers()
                .forEach(
                    dto -> {
                      var maintainer = maintainerRepository.findByEmail(dto.email()).orElseGet(() -> {                         
                        var inner = new Maintainer();
                        inner.setEmail(dto.email());
                        inner.setName(dto.name());
                        inner.setUrl(dto.url());

                        var persisted = maintainerRepository.save(inner);

                        return persisted;
                      });
                      npmPackageVersion.addMaintainer(maintainer);
                    });
          }

          npmPackage.addVersion(npmPackageVersion);
        });
  }

  npmPackageRepository.save(npmPackage);
}
```

Please, consider as well the improvement of returning the returned `Maintainer` instead of the one initialized when saving the data.

Comment: Saving the `Maintainer` first does indeed work! Thank you. However now I'm getting the error `org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.example.demo.Maintainer.Maintainer.npmPackageVersions, could not initialize proxy - no Session`. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Hi @zemirco. I am very happy to hear that saving the maintainer first worked. Regarding your new problem, when are you facing it? I suppose, when trying serializing the information? The problem has to do with the fact that Hibernate is trying to load the `npmPackageVersions` collection when there is no an active transaction in place. Please, if you are using Spring declarative transaction approach, be sure that the necessary methods are correctly annotated with @Transactional. Moreover, did you included the `@JsonManagedReference` and `@JsonBackReference` as in your question, or `@JsonIgnore`?

Comment: Please, can you further describe the problem? I will be glad to help if I can.

Comment: All answers are great and I finally found the solution. Thank you for your help. Unfortunately I can only accept one answer.

Comment: You are welcome @zemirco. I am happy to hear that you were able to find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

you loop over value.maintainers() and probably create 2 new Maintainer with the same email because you check only the database. you should check for unique also the previous maintainers email in npmPackageVersion.

Comment: That actually makes sense. A maintainer might already be the maintainer of a previous version. How do I then associate a new version with an already existing maintainer? It's a  bidirectional relationship. Have a look at my demo repo https://github.com/zemirco/hibernate-issue.